# Placing files under WEB-INF directory and reading them

Tags: java, spring, jboss, spring-integration

We are using JBOSS 5.1.0.GA and spring integration framework. We are placing the configuration files under the `conf` directory of the JBOSS to read them from the classpath. But now we are told that we should move all the configuration files from the `conf` directory to the `WEB-INF` directory of the war file. Everything was working fine When we placed the files under `conf` directory.

```
<bean id="xyz" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                 <value>classpath:CustomerService/property-files/*.properties</value>     
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```

But when we move the configuration files from `conf` directory to `WEB-INF` directory by making the following changes we are getting the Exception`java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

```
<bean id="xyz" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                 <value>/WEB-INF/CustomerService/property-files/*.properties</value>     
            </list>
        </property>
 </bean>
```

The exception details:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [jndi:/localhost/pqawdTestWebApp/WEB-INF/CustomerService/spring-integration/Jobs/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jndi:/localhost/pqawdTestWebApp/WEB-INF/CustomerService/spring-integration/Jobs/
    at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:205)
    at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getFile(UrlResource.java:169)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.doFindPathMatchingFileResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:526)
```

Anybody has idea on what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WEB-INF directory path will not be available as classpath in the standalone Spring project. So, I have moved the configuration files to src/resources folder to import them without any hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Place them in the class path (by some build means).

```
/WEB-INF/classes/CustomerService/property-files/*.properties
```

Comment: That's okay. But how to read them from web.xml and other spring configuration files? What path we need to specify there to read?

Comment: As previously, `classpath:CustomerService/property-files/...` (by spring). For the rest they are normal resource files, `getResourceAsStream("/...")` or whatever,

Comment: That means we need to have a spring bean to read the configuration files under WEB-INF folder. Am I correct?

Comment: No, as all *.properties that are resources with the classes, you can declare a ResourceBundle or Properties and load them. In fact as I saw it, nothing much changes, just instead of the JBoss class loader for all applications now a class loader for the current application loads them. You did not have full file system paths or ../../.. did you?

Comment: It would be great for me if you can provide some sample.

Comment: Pure java: `ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("CustomerService/property-files/real-estate.properties");`.